# How to check downloading data percentage from internet in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsdata

I am trying to download data from internet to NSData in iOS.

When I download data from internet , I can't see how many percentage downloaded from server.

I'm not using UIWebView.

download sound (`.mp3`) from Internet with NSData.

Is there anyways can I know how much data downloaded from internet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What download method are you using?

Comment: implement NSURLConnectionDataDelegate. You'll see there a method that tells you how many bytes the total package has and how many bytes it got now. You should append the new data to the already downloaded one and compute the percentage currentDataBytes/totalBytes.

Comment: Thanks , can u guide me with Sample codes.Please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps:

1) Create a NSURLConnection with a request to the .mp3's URL.

2) Set `self` as the delegate of this connection.

3) Implement the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol. ( Add  next to your class's interface declaration.

4) Implement these methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    if ((statusCode/100) == 2) 
    {
        contentLength = [httpResponse expectedContentLength];
        if (contentLength == NSURLResponseUnknownLength) 
                NSLog(@"unknown content length %ld", contentLength);
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    bytesSum += [data length];
    percent = (float)bytesSum / (float)contentLength;

    // append the new data to the receivedData
    [receivedData appendData:data];     //received data is a NSMutableData ivar.

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
     //the end. Write your data ( stored in receivedData ) to a local .mp3 file.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: error? Did you declare the ivar `long bytesSum` (in your class) ?

Comment: Just curious, why are you dividing `statusCode` by 100 and checking for 2? Why not just check for 200?

Comment: @Undo - because the 2xx is the succesful status code class. Most common , yes , you are interested in 200 OK but you never know. 201 is fine too if you're asking me. Here's the list: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a look at this: [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

You could easily track upload and download process with it and other nice stuff.

Sebastian

Comment: Even the developer of ASIHTTPRequest doesn't recommend you use it anymore http://allseeing-i.com/[request_release];